# Android Permissions Error with FileChooserDialog with the file type picture

Tags: android

today I have this problem.
I have created an FileChooserDialog nd when I select a file type picture/image, it gives me error. This is the Stack Trace:

```
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime: Process: damasoft.manumikychat, PID: 7522
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1234, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:1404 flg=0x1 VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} }} to activity {damasoft.manumikychat/damasoft.manumikychat.Page1}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=7522, uid=10134 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4926)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4969)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:222)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1850)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=7522, uid=10134 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:445)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils.getDataColumn(FileUtils.java:228)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils.getPath(FileUtils.java:322)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at damasoft.manumikychat.Page1.onActivityResult(Page1.java:253)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7138)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4922)
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4969) 
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:222) 
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1850) 
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
07-11 16:18:43.851 7522-7522/damasoft.manumikychat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: add a permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to your Manifest

Comment: I added this permission, but gives me error the same

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html

Comment: I'm android Marshmellow

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem.
I'm an Android Marshmellow(6.0), and so I musted add the permission to acces to External Files. Link to help: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html.